# Explanation of the extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, number-theory

I am looking for some help with understanding the extended Euclidean Algorithm, specifically, this implementation (in Haskell):

```
eGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer,Integer)
eGCD 0 b = (b, 0, 1)
eGCD a b = let (g, s, t) = eGCD (b `mod` a) a
           in (g, t - (b `div` a) * s, s)
```

I understand the Wikipedia [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) but that is based on the invariant

$$ as_i + bt_i = r_i $$
With the recurrence relations:

$$ r_{i+1} = r_{i-1} - q_i r_i $$
$$ s_{i+1} = s_{i-1} - q_i s_i $$
$$ t_{i+1} = t_{i-1} - q_i t_i $$

And the proof follows from Induction.

On the other hand, the implementation above uses the rule

$$ s_{i+1} = t_i - q_{i-1} s_i $$
$$ t_{i+1} = s_i $$

These must be somehow equivalent but I am having trouble seeing it.

Comment: Have you tried working through the computation by hand for some example value of $a,b$, to see whether you can spot any correspondence/pattern before the two computations and see if you can form any conjectures?